# Progressive matrix question - shapes with lines in them

Tags: pattern, visual, progressive-matrix

What is the answer to this question? Please explain why.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only possible answer is

> D, the circle with horizontal lines

Because

> Every row and column must have alternating line direction (vertical/horizontal)

Comment: You don't have to make a distinction between rows and columns, as the patterns you identified work for both.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis The line rule works for both, but the middle row contains two diamond shapes. I guess the shape rule can be ditched anyway. Thanks!

Comment: Oh yes, you're right. I didn't notice that.